# Breadcrumd Space between Arrow

Tags: html, css

I want to create space between everyevery arrow like this image bellow but it not working. I try add `padding` and `margin` but it still not working.
I want to create space between everyevery arrow like this image bellow but it not working. I try add `padding` and `margin` but it still not working.

[image]

I provide this code as your reference

**Html**

```
<div class="container my-2">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 mx-auto justify-content-center align-middle">
<ul id="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#"> Option 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option 2 </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option 3 </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"> Option 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option 5 </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"> Option 6</a></li>
</ul>

    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#breadcrumb li:last-child a:after {
    border: none;
  }
  #breadcrumb li a:before, #breadcrumb li a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    border: 0 solid #3498db;
    border-width: 20px 10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  #breadcrumb li a:before {
    left: -20px;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  #breadcrumb li a:after {
    left: 100%;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: #3498db;
  }
  #breadcrumb li a:hover {
    background-color: #fc1052;
  }
  #breadcrumb li a:hover:before {
    border-color: #fc1052;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  #breadcrumb li a:hover:after {
    border-left-color: #fc1052;
  }
  #breadcrumb li a:active {
    background-color: #fc1052;
  }
  #breadcrumb li a:active:before {
    border-color: #fc1052;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  #breadcrumb li a:active:after {
    border-left-color: #fc1052;
  }
```

Hope you all can help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can get the desired output

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}

#breadcrumb {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

#breadcrumb li {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#breadcrumb li::before,
#breadcrumb li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  left: -1px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  clip-path: polygon(0 2%, 0 100%, 57% 52%);
}

#breadcrumb li::after {
  left: 99.8%;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<ul id="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#"> Option 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option 2 </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option 3 </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"> Option 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option 5 </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"> Option 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But why you not use `<ul>`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very basic solution that can easily be modified.
Basically, you have to use `:before` and `:after` to create the arrow effect

```css
.breadcrumb {
  display:flex;
}

.breadcrumb > li {
  margin-right: 28px;
}

.breadcrumb > li:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.arrow {
  background: #09f;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 28px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}

.arrow:before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 19px 0 19px 20px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
}

.arrow:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 19px 0 19px 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #09f;
}


ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

*,:before,:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a class="arrow" href="#"> Option 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="arrow" href="#">Option 2 </a></li>
  <li><a class="arrow" href="#">Option 3 </a></li>
  <li><a class="arrow" href="#"> Option 4</a></li>
</ul>
```